# Using Json to load all images from server, and displaying them Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What I'm trying to do is get 20 or so images from a folder on the server and display them using masonry.desandro and once scrolled to the bottom it will load another set of 20 images. Just like pinterest.
Currently it does load the images 20 at a time, the only problem I'm having is the first 20 display Masonry but when the next 20 load they aren't displaying Masonry

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
</div>
```

Json

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      // The max number of images to be loaded at a time.
      var limit = 16;

      // JSON data will be assigned to this
      var images = "";

      // to remember where in JSON we are
      // initialize to the value of limit - so that we can load in images
      // before page scroll.
      var currentIndex = limit;

      // When there are fewer than `limit` images left, this
      // value will be the difference between the current index
      // and the length of the images array.
      var stop = limit;

      var grid = $(".grid");

      // Make a GET request to the api
      $.getJSON("***********************/newsite/api.php", function(data) {

        // save the data to be used later.
        images = data.weddingCakes;
        console.log(data);
      })

      // create the first round of images.
      .done(function() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          html += '<div class="grid-item"><img src="' + images[i] + '"></div>';
        }
        grid.append(html)

        .masonry({
            gutter: 3,
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            animate: true
        });
        console.log("masonry")
      })
      .error(function() {
          console.log("error");
      });

      $(document).scroll(function() {
        // get the scoll position with support for IE
        // see http://jsbin.com/egegu3/6/edit?html,js,output
        // for original code.
        var totalHeight, currentScroll, visibleHeight;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
          currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        } else {
          currentScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        totalHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
        visibleHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        // only load more images if the scroll bar is at the bottom
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
              var diff = images.length - currentIndex;
              // if the difference is > 0 then there are more images in the array
              if (diff > 0) {
                stop = diff > limit ? limit : diff;
                getImages(currentIndex, stop);
                currentIndex += stop;
              }

              // otherwise, reset the index before calling getImages()
              else {
                currentIndex = 0;
                stop = diff > limit ? limit : diff;
                getImages(currentIndex, stop);
                currentIndex += stop;
              }
            }
        });
      });

      // gets the path for each image from index to stop
      function getImages(index, stop) {
        var html = "";

        // create the img tags.
        for (var i = index; i < index + stop; i++) {
          html += '<div class="grid-item"><img src="' + images[i] + '"></div>';
        }
        var str = $(html);
        grid.append(html).masonry("appended", str); 
      }
    });
```

My [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93umwj12/2/)

Comment: While reading your code I have one suggestion, you don't need to write $(window).scroll(function() {}) inside document scroll, this register the scroll event multiple number of times(I mean every time document is scrolled), you could differentiate both this function, and I guess having only one will be useful

Comment: If you create jsfiddle for this then I will be able to debug your code easily

Comment: I added the JSfiddle

Comment: Can't run your fiddle, because I can't send AJAX request, would you make working jsfiddle by calling with some static data so that I can move ahead, I have added jquery here -> https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/93umwj12/1/

Comment: I am not getting your images, so I have just used a static image, and this renders them -> https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/93umwj12/3/,

So here I want to ask you is at first you load image side by side but later on they are added as one by one, so you need to load them side by side, that is your question, right? (If I understand correctly)

Comment: That's right I want them to load side by side all of them, with Masonry.

Comment: See the answer, and let me know if you are able to resolve your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost correct just missed a small part while reading [documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html), here while appending elements you need to append HTML elements and pass same to the masonry function.

You were adding string to append and later on you were passing element to the masonry, Also this code -> var str = $(html);  returns Array of HTML elements rather than string, so you need to add these elements to the grid and pass it to masonry

so your little change would be...

```
  // gets the path for each image from index to stop
  function getImages(index, stop) {
    var html = "";

    // create the img tags.
    for (var i = index; i < index + stop; i++) {
      html += '<div class="grid-item"><img src="' + images[i] + '"></div>';
    }
    var str = $(html);
    grid.append(str).masonry("appended", str); // This line is a change
  }
```

I have [dummy fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paragbhyani/93umwj12/4/) for this as well

Comment: The images seem to be loading over top of each other after I uploaded more images to the folder on the server, what would cause that?

Comment: var str = $(html);
    grid.append(str).masonry("appended", str);

should internally handle this ... is it possible to reproduce it on fiddle?

Comment: Also try calling masonry again to layout again ... -> grid.masonry("appended", str).masonry();